# Enable virtual network rules on datalake store in arm template

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

I am trying to enable virtual network rules for a datalake store. Here is a bit of my arm template:

```
{
  "name": "datalakestoretest",
  "type": "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-11-01",
  "properties": {
    "virtualNetworkRules": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "subnetId": "[variables('subnetId')]"
        },
        "name": "vnetrulename"
      }
    ]
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[ concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('vnetName'))]"
  ]
}
```

When I deploy the template, it doesn't enable the vNet rule.

[image]

However, when I go to add the rule in the portal, the config for it already exists, without me having to select the vNet and the subnet.

[image]

So the datalake store is receiving the vNet rules from the template, but it's just not being enabled. How can I enable it?

I have also tried the syntax from [the msft documentation,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datalakestore/2016-11-01/accounts/virtualnetworkrules) so the vNetRule as a separate resource, but it fails to deploy.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `"firewallState": "Enabled",` to the resource properties in the template:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "firewallState": "Enabled",
        "virtualNetworkRules": [
            {
                "properties": {
                    "subnetId": "xxx"
                },
                "name": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    "apiVersion": "2016-11-01",
    "location": "yyy",
    "name": "xxx",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts"
}
```

Comment: Nice one 4c, knew you would come through :D how did you find this out?

Comment: portal.azure.com > f12 (enable developer tools) > click network on the develop tools tab > click enable firewall rules > watch what gets sent to azure. this is generally what you do when things are not documented (or you could use fiddler). thanks for the question. another point why creating arm templates is a horrible experience

Comment: i kinda like, in the context of your question, you say: "knew you would come". if you just say 4c as a single word, it becomes "foresee"))

Comment: wish i could say it was intentional :P